# How to create a Button whose title is right below the image?

Tags: ios

Here is the picture,the title of button is right below the image

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest way would be to have a UIView as a container, chuck in the image and a label arranged like in your picture in the container, then place an invisible button in the container that would cover both the image and the label

Answer (score 0):

set programatically to your button in viewDidLoad() method

```
youtButon.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(50, 0, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set it from storyboard also goto the button attribute inspector check the screenshot[image]

put image in background and set the controls as in image . Here is the result
[image]